# TypeORM official relation example not working

Tags: foreign-keys, typeorm, relation

I want to be able to save and return a list of users with their associated office. To do so, I'm using the official one-to-one relation according to the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations), nestJS, typeORM and mongoDB

user.entity.ts

```
@OneToOne(() => Office, office => office.user) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
@JoinColumn()
office: Office;
```

office.entity.ts

```
@OneToOne(() => User, user => user.office) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
user: User;
```

Saving user

```
const officeId = "615c190d9a99101c6ca6cf43"
const officeObject = await this.officesService.findOne(officeId);
user.office = officeObject; 
const createdUser = await this.usersService.save(user); // user is an object coming from the request and not an actual model instance
```

Following method doesn't return the office reference

```
const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
    select: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'role', 'office'],
    relations: ['office']
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect it's because `'office'` is not a valid column in your `select: []`. Maybe try, say, `'office.columnHere'`? Or just remove the `select` and see if that works.

Comment: @DemiPixel unfortunately it doesn't make any difference

Comment: And can you verify that the user has actually saved the correct `officeId` on it?

Comment: @DemiPixel https://i.postimg.cc/5tQLMp0t/Capture.png yeah it is saved

Answer (score 0):

TypeOrm doesn't seem to make it easy to handle relations automatically: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/655

> ManyToOne/OneToMany/ManyToMany/OneToOne - those decorators are only supported in relational databases, they are not supported by MongoDB. Mongodb is relational-less, so you can't do what you want easily as in relational databases. **You should load your needed data (group) manually and set it to your entity (user) manually.**

> Maybe there will be such feature, but its complex and Im very busy by other tasks at the moment, so it won't be in a near future.

Comment: I've submitted an PR to support MongoDB Relations, hopefully it will be reviewed and accepted soon.